# PullToRefreshListView not supported in Android Jelly Bean

Tags: java, android

I had implemented the PullToRefreshListView from [johan](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh) in an app which works great on every other version of Android except the new Jelly Bean. Does anyone know what might be the reason for this or if there exists a solution to this problem? I have tested this on the android version 4.1.1 with Samsung Galaxy S3.

Also, is it possible to set a filter within the app so that it can recognize if the device is running android version > 4.0. This might be a temporary solution.

Thanks 
Rajat

Comment: It should be throwing a exception, do you have a stacktrace we could look at? Try contacting the author.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out this is an actual problem in Jelly Bean. The solution is in the author's page:

You need to change the following lines in the PullToRefreshListView class:

```
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    setSelection(1);
}
```

More [here](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh/pull/53)

All the best

Answer (score 0):

The temporary solution you asked is detailed in this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html) it's called lazy loading.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the same problem we are talking about.

Comment: `Also, is it possible to set a filter within the app so that it can recognize if the device is running android version > 4.0. This might be a temporary solution`. You use a lazy loading exactly as described in blog post (it uses the multi-touch as example) to implement the pull to refresh on the acceptable devices and do not crash on unacceptable devices.